# Why can't I change an objects attribute in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I made 2 different rectangels in QML. The fisrts one's color is red and the other one is blue. Then I wanted to change the first one's color to white. QT builds and runs the code perfectly but the color doesn't change. How can I fix the problem?
Edit: I already did clean and rebuild

```
Rectangle{
        id: rect1
        x: 10
        y: 10
        width: 50
        height: 50
        color: "red"
}
Rectangle{
        id: rect2
        x: 90
        y: 10
        width: 50
        height: 50
        color: "blue"
}
```

to

```
Rectangle{
        id: rect1
        x: 10
        y: 10
        width: 50
        height: 50
        color: "white"
}
Rectangle{
        id: rect2
        x: 90
        y: 10
        width: 50
        height: 50
        color: "blue"
}
```

Comment: Sometimes, Qt Creator does not detect changes in the QML files. Try to clean and rebuild your app

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. I already did it but it didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: Please show the code you use to change the colour. This code has fixed colours.

Comment: This is the code. When I run the code the first rect is still red @Mitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run `qmake` because QML & QSS files need to generate new make files again to have an effect on your program..

Answer (score 1):

You can also try **Tools->QML/JS->Reset code model**